# ClassCastException on JBoss deploy

Tags: exception, deployment, jboss6.x, jboss-weld

EDIT: When renaming ProfileService.class to ProfileService2.class, it worked... Name clash somewhere?

When trying to deploy my application, I get the following exception:

```
2012-03-20 11:38:51,433 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] (HDScanner) Error installing to Start: name=jboss.j2ee:jar=career-portal.war,name=ProfileService,service=EJB3,type=nointerface-view-jndi-binder state=Create: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.aop.generatedproxies.AOPProxy$2 cannot be cast to javax.naming.Context
at org.jboss.util.naming.Util.createSubcontext(Util.java:70) [jboss-common-core.jar:2.2.17.GA]
at org.jboss.util.naming.NonSerializableFactory.rebind(NonSerializableFactory.java:222) [jboss-common-core.jar:2.2.17.GA]
at org.jboss.ejb3.nointerface.impl.jndi.SessionlessBeanNoInterfaceViewBinder.bind(SessionlessBeanNoInterfaceViewBinder.java:91) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.ejb3.nointerface.impl.jndi.AbstractNoInterfaceViewBinder.start(AbstractNoInterfaceViewBinder.java:77) [:6.0.0.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_24]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_24]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_24]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_24]
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:60) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:168) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction$JoinpointDispatchWrapper.execute(KernelControllerContextAction.java:257) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(ExecutionWrapper.java:47) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:125) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchJoinPoint(KernelControllerContextAction.java:72) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.LifecycleAction.installActionInternal(LifecycleAction.java:202) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.deploy(HDScanner.java:240) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.complete(HDScanner.java:192) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.TwoPCActionWrapper.doComplete(TwoPCActionWrapper.java:57) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.complete(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:74) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.prepare(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:95) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.ModificationSession.prepare(ModificationSession.java:87) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.internalPerfom(AbstractActionController.java:234) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.performWrite(AbstractActionController.java:213) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:150) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:135) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:146) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:90) [:0.2.2]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441) [:1.6.0_24]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317) [:1.6.0_24]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150) [:1.6.0_24]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98) [:1.6.0_24]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [:1.6.0_24]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204) [:1.6.0_24]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_24]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_24]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_24]
```

ProfileService.java

```
package com.xdin.competence.service;

import com.xdin.competence.dao.ProfileDAO;
import com.xdin.competence.dao.UserDAO;
import com.xdin.competence.entities.User;
import com.xdin.competence.entities.competence.*;
import com.xdin.competence.tree.ProfileCompetenceTreeNode;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.primefaces.model.TreeNode;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Stateless
public class ProfileService {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ProfileService.class.getName());

    @Inject private ProfileDAO profileDAO;
    @Inject private UserDAO userDAO;

    public ProfileService() {
    }

    public User saveCompetenceProfile(User user, Template template, List<TreeNode> trees, List<CustomCompetence> customCompetences, String comment) {
        Profile p = new Profile(user, template);
        for(TreeNode node : trees){
            p.getProfileCompetences().addAll(getProfileCompetencesFromTree(node, p));
        }
        p.setUserComment(comment);
        for(CustomCompetence cc : customCompetences){
            cc.setProfile(p);
        }
        p.setCustomCompetences(customCompetences);
        profileDAO.create(p);
        user.setActiveCompetenceProfile(p);
        return userDAO.save(user);
    }

    private List<ProfileCompetence> getProfileCompetencesFromTree(TreeNode root, Profile parent){
        // Add profileCompetences
        ArrayList<ProfileCompetence> pcList = new ArrayList<ProfileCompetence>();
        for(TreeNode group : root.getChildren()){
            for(TreeNode pcNode : group.getChildren()){
                ProfileCompetence pc = ((ProfileCompetenceTreeNode)pcNode.getData()).getPc();
                if(pc.getLevel() > 0 || (pc.getLevelGoal() != null && pc.getLevelGoal() > 0) || (pc.getComments() != null && !pc.getComments().isEmpty())){
                    pc.setProfile(parent);
                    pcList.add(pc);
                }
            }
        }
        return pcList;
    }

}
```

As you can see, nothing is weird with ProfileService, just a very normal session bean. It's also worth to mention that I can still use the application, regardless of the exception.

What could be the cause?

Using JBoss 6 with Weld.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a bug in JBoss, Naming a class ProfileService was apparently not allowed. Renaming the class solved the problem.